# Integration of Grafana dashboards in JS/React web application components

Tags: web-applications, grafana, micro-frontend

Is it possible to integrate Grafana dashboards in JS/React web application components? We are searching for an alternaive to an IFrame integration, e.g., using DOMs in React.

We are using a micro frontend technology that is written in JS/React.

Thanks

Comment: Any feedback concerning the integration of Grafana dashboards in JS/React web applications?

Comment: I would also be interested...

Comment: Same here.  Sounds like this is a bit old and no one has either found an answer or run back across it yet.